# Using Angular ng-src with absolute urls not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an image with an absolute url like "https://someimageurl.com/image.png" that is hosted via a third-party service.

```
// in controller
$scope.image = 'https://someimageurl.com/image.png'
```

I'm trying to use Angular's `ng-src` directive like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{myCtrl.image}}" />
```

When I inspect element the image url is injected into the DOM, but it's not showing up. It a 1x1 dimension blank image. However, I see the image come in (with 200 status code) via the Network tab, but its just 1x1.

When I try using a url like "http://placehold.it/350x150" it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is there any console log error? Ive noticed that the url that didnt work for you is hosted on https and not http

Answer (score 2):

I have an identical version of this working correctly by having the 'http://someimageurl.com/' added in the img tag, and the dynamic part loaded with a scope call. Example:

```
<img ng-src="http://someimageurl.com/{{myCtrl.image_path}}" />
```

Comment: Good one, use path.

Comment: Looks like that's how it's written in the Angular Docs as well https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think you've made a confusion with the `controllerAs` syntax. You have to add members on the controller instance (i.e., `this`) instead of `$scope` in this case, otherwise you should change `{{ myCtrl.image }}` to `{{ image }}`.

```
// in controller

var myCtrl = this;
myCtrl.image = 'https://someimageurl.com/image.png'

// template

<img ng-src="{{myCtrl.image}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably configure your angular app to whitelist those urls. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider